# unable to set text with syncvars in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I'm ultimately trying to show active players, but I'm having trouble setting the value of a text box.

My understanding is that once a player joins, I need to use syncvars to show all player names on each client. So to start, I'm trying this...

```
[SyncVar(hook = "OnPlayerName")]
public string name;

void OnPlayerName(string newPlayerName)
{
    playerlist.text = name;

}

public override void OnStartClient()
{
    name = "terrance";
}
```

When I run this, the text box is empty. If I set the text without syncvars, it works. Of course, the change is only visible to the local client if I do it without syncvars.

RESOLUTION:
the parameter newPlayerName needs to match the variable name, so in this case "name"...

```
void OnPlayerName(string name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hooking it to a function that doesnt exist,

> "OnPlayName"

Should be

```
[SyncVar(hook = "OnPlayerName")]
public string name;
```

Comment: Good catch, but that's not it. I've updated my code above.

Comment: Also you seem to be doing nothing with the parameter of OnPlayerName

Comment: But, you did get me looking in the right place. Obvious once you see it, but the parameter for onplayername doesn't match the variable name. Thanks for the helpful kick in the butt.

Comment: Yep - seeing your comment now. That was the issue.